# Jest - Could not locate module with dynamic import template string

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs

well I a have a setup with Webpack and Jest for testing react and also using Webpack's aliases using the "@" sign for the directory of my project which is "src/app", I know also it must be mapped into jest.config using the "moduleNameMapper" property to properly align with that alias.

the problem is that there's an `<Icon />` component which intern imports dynamically .svg icons using ES dynamic import.

this is the Regex for that mapping for jest.config.js

'^@/': '/src/app/$1'

but it breaks ONLY when testing

everything works fine except when testing

my folder structure is the following:

```
config/
 webpack-config/

src/
 app/
  assets/
   img/
    some images
   svg/
    icons/
     cart.svg
  components/
   base/
   core/
   shared/
   ...
 client/
  ...
 server/
  ...
```

this is the Webpack alias I'm using:

```
module.exports = {
  extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.json', '.jsx', '.css'],
  modules: paths.resolveModules,
  alias: {
    '@': paths.srcApp, // that just point
  }
};
```

this is my jest.config file:

```
const paths = require('./config/paths');

module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}'],
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime',
    '<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js',
  ],
  // A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up the testing framework before each test.
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>config/jest/setup.js'],
  testMatch: [
    '<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}',
    '<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}',
  ],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testURL: 'http://localhost',
  modulePaths: ['src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@[/](.+)': '<rootDir>/src/app/$1',
  },
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.css$': '<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js',
    '^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json|svg)$)': '<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$'],
  moduleDirectories: paths.resolveModules,
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'node', 'mjs'],
};
```

this is the component I'm testing

```
// @flow strict
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import './Icon.scss';

type PropsType = {
  name: string,
  selected?: string,
  size: number | string
};

const Icon = ({ name, size }: PropsType) => {
  const [iconPath, setIconPath] = useState('');
  (async () => {
    const icon = await import(`@/assets/svg/icons/${name}.svg`);
    setIconPath(icon.default);
  })();

  return (
    <img
      alt={`icon ${name}`}
      className="icon"
      style={{
        height: `${size}px`,
        width: `${size}px`,
      }}
      src={iconPath}
    />
  );
};

Icon.defaultProps = {
  size: 16,
};

export default Icon;
```

and this it's test

```
// @flow strict
import React from 'react';
import {
  render,
} from 'react-testing-library';

import Icon from './Icon';

describe('Icon', () => {
  it('should have "name" with the path of the icon', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Icon name="cart" />);  
  });
});
```

and this is the output

```
Configuration error:

    Could not locate module @/assets/svg/icons/${name}.svg mapped as:
    /Users/jero/Documents/my-shit/react-shop/src/app/assets/svg/icons/${name}.svg.

    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^@[\/](.+)/": "/Users/jero/Documents/my-shit/react-shop/src/app/$1"
      },
      "resolver": null
    }
```

the interesting thing is that when I use this regex for jest.config

```
moduleNameMapper: {
 '/^@\/(.*)$/': '<rootDir>/src/app$1'
}
```

the error is gone about, but it breaks when a component imports other components when testing:

```
 FAIL  src/app/components/shared/ImgLoader/ImgLoader.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@/components/base/Spinner/Spinner' from 'ImgLoader.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './ImgLoader.js'
        './ImgLoader.scss'
        './ImgLoader.test.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['js', 'json', 'jsx', 'node', 'mjs'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

      2 | import React, { useState } from 'react';
      3 | 
    > 4 | import Spinner from '@/components/base/Spinner/Spinner';
        | ^
      5 | 
      6 | import './ImgLoader.scss';
      7 | 

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:230:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/components/shared/ImgLoader/ImgLoader.js:4:1)
```

and this is the `<ImageLoader />`

```
// @flow strict
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Spinner from '@/components/base/Spinner/Spinner';

import './ImgLoader.scss';

type PropsType = {
  src: string
};

function ImgLoader({ src }: PropsType) {
  const [imgObj, setImg] = useState({ img: null, isLoading: true });
  const image = new Image();

  image.onload = () => setImg({ img: image.src, isLoading: false });
  image.src = src;

  return (
    imgObj.isLoading ? (<Spinner />) : (<img className="imgLoader img-fluid" src={imgObj.img} alt="img" />)
  );
}

export default ImgLoader;
```

and its test offcourse

```
// @flow strict

import React from 'react';
import {
  render,
} from 'react-testing-library';
import ImgLoader from './ImgLoader';

describe('ImgLoader', () => {
  it('tests \'src\'', () => {
    const src = 'https://static.street-beat.ru/upload/resize_cache/iblock/d69/450_450_1/d699afc7b3428f2f51c2f2de6665b506.jpg';
    const { container } = render(<ImgLoader src={src} />);
    console.log('container', container);

  });
});
```

I believe is something related with the dynamic import?

Comment: the real issue is with the dynamic import, I think is eagerly parsing that string `@/assets/svg/icons/${name}.svg`

Answer (score 16):

here's how I fixed it, the problem is that Jest for some reason, it complains when using template literals inside the dynamic import. so to fix it just use normal string concatenation and that's it.

```
(async () => {
  // $FlowIgnore
  const icon = await import('@/assets/svg/icons/' + name + '.svg');
  setIconPath(icon.default);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this. I could not believe that the template literal was the cause. Very strange issue!

Comment: Yeah, I was very stocked at this, but well, Is now open for everyone :)

Comment: There is now a related issue about this https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7511

Comment: Thank you bro you saved me hours of trouble.

Comment: This should be fixed in new versions of jest. If you're using Vue CLI 4, it still uses 24.9.0 from before this issue was fixed. You can upgrade to Vue CLI 5 if you need to fix this. It's just that it's in beta right now.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be solved without removing template literals by replacing Jest's `--watch` flag with `--watchAll`

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me, just curious why.. but don't have much time for digging (I have my theory why)

Comment: it is indeed worked but it seems run too frequently as watchAll re-runs every char change, but watch only re-runs on save